# Multiple fetch requests with setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm writing a component that will make fetch requests to two different paths of a site, then set its states to the resulting response data. My code looks something like this:

```
export default class TestBeta extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            recentInfo: [],
            allTimeInfo: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        Promise.all([
            fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent'),
            fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime')
        ])
        .then(([res1, res2]) => [res1.json(), res2.json()])
        .then(([data1, data2]) => this.setState({
            recentInfo: data1, 
            alltimeInfo: data2
        }));
    }
```

However, when I go to render my two states, I find that they are actually still empty, and in fact have not been set to anything. I feel like I might be using either the Promises or fetch() API wrong, or misunderstanding how setState works, or a combination of things. I tested around and found that after the first then(), my data1 and data2 were still Promises for some reason, and had not become actual JSON objects yet. Either way, I cannot figure out for the life of me what's going on here. Any help or explanation would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to do a Promise.all on the res.json() as well as that also returns a promise. Currently your second then() block is never processed

Comment: so would it be: Promise.all([...]).then(Promise.all([res1, res2] => ...).then(Promise.all([data1, data2]) => ...)?

Comment: Yes `Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()])`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
export default class TestBeta extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            recentInfo: [],
            allTimeInfo: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        Promise.all([
            fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent'),
            fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime')
        ])
        .then(([res1, res2]) => Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()]))
        .then(([data1, data2]) => this.setState({
            recentInfo: data1, 
            alltimeInfo: data2
        }));
    }
```

If you return Promise in `then` handler, then it's resolved to value. If you return anything else (like Array in your example), it will be passed as is. So you need to wrap your array of promises to `Promise.all` to make it Promise type