# Where is the right place to call the httpRequest of an API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit confused on where I should call an API while using React, I've been putting the call on componentDidMount and doing setState there, like so:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {info: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ObtenerVariables(this.props.enlace1, this.props.enlace2);
  }
  ObtenerVariables(consulta1, consulta2){
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', consulta1,false);
    httpRequest.send();
    var cons1 =JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
    var cantArticulos = cons1.data[0].cantidad_articulos;

    httpRequest.open('GET', consulta2,false);
    httpRequest.send();
    var cons2 =JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
    var cantAutores = cons2.data[0].cant_autores;

    this.setState({ info: [cantArticulos, cantAutores] })
  }
```

and then just access the information like so
`this.state.info[0]`

however I've seen some people online say that this is not good because it will give you performance issues, which is exactly the opposite of what I want, I need the website to load faster.
Is this a bad practice and is it affecting performance of the website? What would be a better way to do this? Take into account that this website needs to make around 16 API requests.

Comment: componentDidMount in classes and useEffect(() => {}, []) in functional components.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is right way to do API call in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742334/what-is-right-way-to-do-api-call-in-react-js)

Comment: @EmileBergeron sort of, i had already seen that question but my question is more of a "is doing it this way affecting performance and is there a more efficient way to do it"

Comment: While not impossible to make it work with `XMLHttpRequest`, you should really consider the new `fetch` API or the `axios` request lib.

Comment: The performance hit comes from the fact that these requests are not parallel, so it's waiting for the first one to finish before sending the next one, which looks unnecessary here.

Comment: Maybe this one is a better question to help with your use-case: [Multiple fetch requests with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754270/1218980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place for Api call is `componentDidMount` for `class component` and `useEffect(() => { /* ... */}, [])` for `functional component`.

Please check both example below:

**Class Component**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PostListPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                console.log(posts);
                this.setState({posts:posts});
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.posts? this.state.posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>) : null
                    }
                </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

**Functional Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function PostListPage() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts? posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>) : null
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```